# Stuck with comparison arrays with objects which has IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, comparison

**I have 2 arrays with objects**

1. With car brands

```
const brands = [
   { id: 1, name: "Mercedes Benz", bodyType: [1, 3] },
   { id: 2, name: "Audi", bodyType: [1, 2] },
   { id: 3, name: "BMW", bodyType: [3, 4] },
   { id: 4, name: "Mazda", bodyType: [1, 2, 4] }
];
```

2. With body types

```
const bodyTypes = [
   { id: 1, type: "Sedan"},
   { id: 2, type: "Coupe"},
   { id: 3, type: "Hatchback"},
   { id: 4, type: "SUV"}
];
```

3. I have picked types

```
const pickedTypes = [2, 4] // Coupe & SUV
```

How to compare this two arrays to get new array with brands that has body types that in pickedTypes

**There is my try to get an array that I want**

```
const brands = [
   { id: 1, name: "Mercedes Benz", bodyType: [1, 3] },
   { id: 2, name: "Audi", bodyType: [1, 2] },
   { id: 3, name: "BMW", bodyType: [3, 4] },
   { id: 3, name: "Mazda", bodyType: [1, 2, 4] }
];

const bodyTypes = [
   { id: 1, type: "Sedan"},
   { id: 2, type: "Coupe"},
   { id: 3, type: "Hatchback"},
   { id: 4, type: "SUV"}
];

const pickedTypes = [2, 4] // coupe & suv

let newBrandsByPickedTypes = [];

// loop for every type
for(let i = 0; i < pickedTypes.length; i++){
  // loop for every brand
  for(let k = 0; k < brands.length; k++){
      // loop for every type in brand
      brands[k].bodyType.forEach((type) => {
        // if brand has type that in pickedTypes push this brand to newBrandsByPickedTypes 
        if(type === pickedTypes[i]){
            newBrandsByPickedTypes.push(brands[k])
        }
      })
  }

}

newBrandsByPickedTypes && console.log(newBrandsByPickedTypes); // output audi, mazda, bmw
```

*Im stuck in this many loops actually..*

It looks like it's work but I have something like a warning: [circular object Object]]

Comment: Actually Mazda was added 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter from the brands array based on whether any of the ids in pickedTypes is present in individual brand's bodyType array. Here is a possible solution

```
brands.filter(brand => pickedTypes.some(type => brand.bodyType.includes(type))).map(brand => brand.name)
```

Output

```
['Audi', 'BMW', 'Mazda']
```

In this case, since pickedType contains ids already and not names, bodyTypes array is not required, if pickedTypes had "Sedan", "Coupe" etc, you could have mapped the ids from bodyTypes and searched with that array

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're trying to compare two arrays to get a new array with brands that have body types that are in the pickedTypes array. Your code works, but you're getting a warning message about a circular object.

This warning usually means that your code is creating a circular reference between objects, causing an infinite loop. I suggest checking your objects to see if there are any circular references in them.

Also, you can simplify your code by using the filter() method to filter out the brands that don't have body types in the pickedTypes array. Here's an example:

```
brands.filter(brand => pickedTypes.some(type => brand.bodyType.includes(type))).map(brand => brand.name)
```

This code uses the filter() method to filter out the brands that don't have any body types in the pickedTypes array. The some() method is used to check if any of the body types in the brand are in the pickedTypes array.

I hope this helps!